# Pairing a sports score & respective team, and creating a column if the home team won or lost

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this data:

```
            Date               Visitor GVisitor                  Home GHome Att.
      1990-10-06         Winnipeg Jets        5       Edmonton Oilers     3 <NA>
```

All of these columns are separate. I want to create a "Win" column that gives a "Yes" or "No" if the Home team won or not. So in this case, the Jets won the game, so the Home team, Edmonton, lost. How do I put that Yes/No result in its own column? Thanks

---

```
GVisitor = number of goals visiting team scored

GHome = number of goals home team scored

Att. = attendance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a column with the result of the logical test `GHome > GVisitor`

In base r, if your data frame is called df:

```
df$Win <- df$GHome > df$GVisitor
```

In dplyr, you'd use `mutate`:

```
new_df <- mutate(df, Win = GHome > GVisitor)
```

This column will have `TRUE` exactly when the home team scored more goals than the visiting team.

Since you have the `dplyr` tag, here's some sample data and result using the `dplyr` approach:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(GHome = sample(0:5, 6, replace = TRUE), GVisitor = sample(0:5, 6, replace = TRUE))
mutate(df, Win = GHome > GVisitor)
#   GHome GVisitor     Win
# 1     1        3   FALSE
# 2     4        5   FALSE
# 3     2        3   FALSE
# 4     5        2    TRUE
# 5     5        5   FALSE
# 6     0        2   FALSE
```

Notice that a tie results in a `FALSE` value, e.g., row 5. If you want this to be handled differently, alter your logical test accordingly.

Comment: That's great, thanks. My intention is to use that "HomeWin" as my outcome for a decision tree, and predict sports scores (starting small, obviously ha). Thanks!

Comment: @papelr you might be interested in this [538 article](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/a-home-playoff-game-is-a-big-advantage-unless-you-play-hockey/) about home field advantage:

Comment: Awesome, great article - and thanks the for dplyr help too! That gives me an outcome to work with. Appreciate it much!